# How to download SSL certificates from a S3 bucket with necessary policies to a Gradle application running on my FARGATE container

Tags: amazon-web-services, gradle, amazon-s3, aws-sdk, aws-fargate

Have a springboot application (gradle) running in my ECS FARGATE container on HTTPS protocol. Want to store the .PKCS12 file which contains the certificate and key on an AWS S3 bucket and download it to the application's classpath when it runs on FARGATE.
Any pointers or links to github code would be much appreciated. THanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am probably missing the crux of what you are asking, but you should be able to get the file directly from S3 in a command in your Dockerfile.  First you should install the AWS CLI, using a process like https://github.com/fstab/docker-aws-cli/blob/master/Dockerfile . Once you have the CLI, you should be able to have a command like:

```
RUN aws s3 cp s3://myBucket/myPrefix/cert.pkcs12 .
RUN cp cert.pkcs12 $MYCLASSPATHDIR
```

**Edit** To copy a file directly from an S3 location to a specific location on your instance, the `cp` command works like the Unix command of the same name. The second parameter is the target location. So you can just do:

```
RUN aws s3 cp s3://myBucket/myPrefix/cert.pkcs12 $MYCLASSPATHDIR
```

Comment: I am trying to use the AWS SDK in my application to download the certificate directly to the classpath from S3. Would that be possible?

Comment: Yes, I misread your comment and added an edit. But to download the certificate with your application, you should be able to do so. For example, the Java SDK provides S3 clients to download objects: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/index.html

Comment: Okay, thanks! So through SDK I can download the .pkcs12 file into my classpath of an application running on FARGATE container.

Comment: Do you mind accepting the answer if this is sufficient?